# digits after decimal point

Tags: objective-c

how to get digits after decimal point from float number in objective c

Comment: As floats do not exactly map to base 10 numbers I think you need to explain what you want this for (e.g. 1./5. will not give a number with 2 decimal places)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is C-style, but I imagine the process would be the same.

```
int decimals = (number -((int)number) );

while( decimals > 0.0 )
{
    reportNextNumber( (int)(decimals*10) );
    decimals = (number -((int)number) );
}
```

Comment: What's reportNextNumber()?  My friend Google doesn't seem to know either.

Comment: Will this really work due to float precision issues?  If you're taking the decimal remainder of a float, you could have an eensy teensy bit of non-zero digits at the end of `decimals` that will really mess up this calculation.  No?

Answer (score 0):

this code works

```
CGFloat x = 2.43;
// CGFloat x = 3.145;
// CGFloat x = 2.0003;
// CGFloat x = 1.0;
// CGFloat x = 3.1415926535;

NSLog(@"%f -> %@", x, @([self numberOfFractionDigits:x]));



- (NSString *)numberOfFractionDigits:(CGFloat)number {
    CGFloat fractionalPart = number - (NSInteger)number;
    NSMutableString *r = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    while (fractionalPart) {
        [r appendFormat:@"%@", @((NSUInteger)(fractionalPart * 10 + .5))];
        number *= 10;
        fractionalPart = number - (NSInteger)number;
    }
    return r;
}
```

output:

2.430000 -> 43

3.145000 -> 145

2.000300 -> 0003

1.000000 ->

3.141593 -> 1415926535 // for x = 3.1415926535;